# Ember TextField valueBinding with dynamic property

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to write a generic view that handles custom fields in my app, but I'm having a hard time getting this to work.  Here's the scenario - I have a `fieldDef` object which defines the custom fields, and a `valueObject` which has an array, `customFields`, which has the values. What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="valueObject.customFields.[fieldDef.name]"}}
```

Obviously that doesn't work because it treats `fieldDef.name` as a literal. I've tried overriding the TextField class, but can't seem to get it to bind.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ember can't bind to an array index, so you'll have to work around it. One solution is to limit yourself to a one-way binding, where your textfield updates the values hash. If you're planning to submit the form after the user presses a button, this should do the trick.

Define an array of field ids in your controller and a hash for their values to go in.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  fieldIds: ['name', 'email', 'whatever'],
  fieldValues: {} // {name: 'user', email: 'user@...', ...}
});
```

Now extend `Ember.TextField` to update your values hash when a text field changes. You'll need to pass each instance a `fieldId` and a reference to the `values` hash from your controller.

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  fieldId: null,
  values: null,

  valueChange: function() {
      var fieldId = this.get('fieldId');
      var values = this.get('values');
      if (values && fieldId) values[fieldId] = this.get('value');
  }.observes('value')
});
```

The template is simple.

```
{{#each fieldId in fieldIds}}
  <label>{{fieldId}}</label>
  {{view App.TextField fieldIdBinding="fieldId" valuesBinding="fieldValues"}}
  <br/>
{{/each}}
```

[Here it is fleshed out in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXnWj/).

Comment: Thanks - I used an approach very similar to this.

Comment: Do I need to declare App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({}) in the controller if I just want a normal textfield with a valueBinding attached to it?

Answer (score 1):

@ahmacleod great answer man. Just in case anyone is interested it works great extending select too:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Select.extend({
  fieldId: null,
  values: null,

  valueChange: function() {
    var fieldId = this.get('fieldId');
    var values = this.get('values');
    if (values && fieldId) values[fieldId] = this.get('value');
  }.observes('value')
});
```

Call it as an normal component (components/dynamic-select.js)

```
{{#each id in fieldIds}}
   {{dynamic-select content=fieldIds fieldIdBinding="header"       
     valuesBinding="fields"}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind input values with dynamic keys(variables) of objects with help of **mut** helper now.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_binding-dynamic-attribute

You can access it like this,

```
var Object = {};
var key = "firstName";
```

We can bind key in input helper like this,

```
{{input value=(mut (get Object key))}}

{{Object.firstName}} // Prints the dynamic value in textbox
```