# Ember - dynamic value binding

Tags: ember.js

I have a seemingly simple requirement in an Ember app that is giving me fits.

I want to take this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="fields.firstName"}}
```

And make the firstName field a variable.  This is the intent, but obviously doesn't work:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="fields.{{fieldName}}"}}
```

Am I missing something obvious?  This seems like it should be a very basic thing, but I've tried probably 10 different things I think "should" work but none of them work as intended.

Comment: Use just `value=fields.fieldName`. No quotes

Comment: That's not correct.  That binds to the key "fieldName" in fields, which doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the `TextField` track the variable directly you would need to have the `TextField` track a computed property, and have the computed property track the variable.

For example if you had both a `firstName` and a `lastName` you can do something like this...

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  //These are the fields you would want to edit
  firstName: 'Tom',
  lastName: 'Dale',

  //this is so that we can create a selectbox to choose which field to edit
  availableFields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
  selectedField: 'firstName',

  //This is the computed property which tracks the selected field
  //The text input would be bound to this
  fieldValue: function(key, value){
    var selectedField = this.get('selectedField');
    if (value) {
      this.set(selectedField, value);
    }
    return this.get(selectedField);
  }.property('selectedField')

});
```

You can see a working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/juhika/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's it!  I wasn't leveraging the fact that computed properties can be used to set the value in question.

Comment: Note that the syntax for computed properties has now changed:   http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html#toc_new-computed-syntax

Answer (score 4):

You can bind input values with dynamic keys(variables) with help of **mut** helper now

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_binding-dynamic-attribute

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=(mut (get fields fieldName))}}
```

Check the following example,

```
var Object = {};
var key = "firstName";
```

We can bind key in input helper like this,

```
{{input value=(mut (get Object key))}}

{{Object.firstName}} // Prints the dynamic value in textbox
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a computed property which would listen to `fieldName` and then return the value.

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jaxoquhali/2/edit?html,js,output) for example. Is this what you're trying to do? Have to keep in mind that Handlebars is pretty "dumb", intentionally, and can't really do complex computation the way you might be used to from Angular or another framework. The controller should be handling all of that.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  fields: {
    field1: 'test',
    field2: 'test2'
  },

  fieldName: '',

  myFieldName: function() {
    var fields = this.get('fields');
    var fieldName = this.get('fieldName');

    return fields[fieldName];

  }.property('fieldName')

});
```

Then, in your view, bind to myFieldName.

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=myFieldName}}
```

Comment: I think your example has the same issue mine does. The idea is if you try to display fields later, the only way it properly binds is if you use a constant string.

Comment: I think that's intended behavior. The view layer shouldn't really be doing computational things, such as accessing an element of an array or object. It also allows you to easily test that behavior as it's encapsulated all within the controller logic.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic value binding create a computed property on the controller:

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Also I believe valueBinding is deprecated. Use value instead.

Here is another similar question: [Ember TextField valueBinding with dynamic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162869/ember-textfield-valuebinding-with-dynamic-property)

Comment: This is not helpful. That other question is 1.5 years old, which is forever in Ember time, and it also doesn't fully answer the question.  And doing a bit of digging leads me to no sign that valueBinding is deprecated.

Comment: valueBinding is definitely deprecated. You responded quite fast. Did you try to create a computed property in the controller and reference it in the template as the value passed to the textfield? I would create a ember.jsbin for you but honestly I'm at work and just breezing through here.

Comment: I have tried a lot of ways to fix this, including what you suggested .  If you want to be helpful, please give actual code that does the thing.  It should be a one liner, with possibly a small computed property function so it's not like I'm asking a whole lot.  But if you don't know the answer, please don't just throw something up that you think "should" work.  The thing that "should" work doesn't work here.