# Emberjs making a data binding an array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Im trying to create a form where a user can add as many details as they want. So for example the form has an input field for name. The client has the option to add that name or to keep adding names.

I want to make the data binding value an array of names. If not it just return the last input with the value of name.

I tried doing something like this:

```
{{input value=name[]}}
```

but that automatically threw an error. How can I accomplish this in emberJs?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Ember doesn't accept indices in bindings expressions. All I can propose is to use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162869/ember-textfield-valuebinding-with-dynamic-property).